# LibreOffice Base - How to populate listbox values(not sql/table) from code?

Tags: libreoffice-base

I am toying with Base but am stuck on how to set the ListSource of a ListBox with an array of values rather than data from a query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To add entries manually, edit the form and create a new list box.  Right-click on the control and choose `Control`. At `General` tab of control properties window, edit `List entries` property: add the first item, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then add another item.

From [How to Programmatically add or remove items in ListBox FORM control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667166/how-to-programmatically-add-or-remove-items-in-listbox-form-control/33702458#33702458), @Lyrl writes:

> The listbox array content is clunky; it's actually easier to work with if the form is connected to a Base file and the listbox content is determined by an SQL string.

That page also shows macro code to populate the list with an array of values.

> oListBox.StringItemList() = Array("One", "Two", "Three")